# How to dynamically cast numbers from firestore to long or double in Kotlin?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I've noticed that I can explicitly define numbers as Longs in Kotlin when getting documents from Google's Firestore database, but reading the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) I see that it is a "64-bit double precision, IEEE 754." type, but [according to Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-double/) that is a Double.

I've testing getting the numbers as Longs and Doubles and noticed that it will accept both and just automatically drop everything past the decimal point. This behavior seems to be the same as `Double.toLong()` in Kotlin.

Is there anyway to dynamically cast as the right number type without casting all values as doubles and then converting to long if the number in the decimal place is simply a 0?

EDIT: (providing minimum code as requested in a comment)

When number on Firestore console is 5

```
Log.d(TAG, "number: ${doc.getLong(MY_FIELD_NAME)}") //5
Log.d(TAG, "number: ${doc.getDouble(MY_FIELD_NAME)}") //5.0
```

When number on Firestore console is 5.5

```
Log.d(TAG, "number: ${doc.getLong(MY_FIELD_NAME)}") //5
Log.d(TAG, "number: ${doc.getDouble(MY_FIELD_NAME)}") //5.5
```

If it matters in my data scheme whether the number is 5 or 5.1, is the only safe way to cast as a double and just check the decimal point numbers or can the document conversion check at that time?

Comment: Instead of describing the problem (or in addition to it) can you show the [minimal code with which you can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `getLong`, which is obviously declared to return a long value, on a field that contains a floating point number, it's always going to truncate the decimal part of the number.  That's not Firestore, that's just the JVM default behavior.

> If it matters in my data scheme whether the number is 5 or 5.1, is the only safe way to cast as a double and just check the decimal point numbers or can the document conversion check at that time?

If you want to find out the type of the value of a field, you should first access it as `Any`, which will give you the raw data as the SDK finds more appropriate:

```
val foo: Any? = doc.get("foo")
```

Then check to see what type it is dynamically and decide what to do with it:

```
if (foo is Long) {
    val long = foo
}
else if (foo is Double) {
    val double = foo
}
```